# How to maintain code in two separate code bases for two different laravel projects?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

So I am working on two different applications using laravel and both of them need a lot of the migrations, seeds, models, controllers, routes and so on similar to each other. In fact in most cases, they are absolutely same. What is the best solution to avoid redundancy in such a case.

The best solution I came up with was to extract a package and then use that package in both the applications but there are drawbacks. Every time I need to add a new feature which needs to be added to both of the laravel application, the package needs to updated. Once the package is updated, the main applications are updated. Sometimes small syntactical changes make me change something in the package and then update the packages again to see if it is working. But soon it becomes painful like this.

I have also tried using symlinks in composer file so that the package gets updated as I am working inside an application which uses them, but I still have to update the other application. Moreover, I still have to remove the symlinks before I push because the symlinks break in CI. They need the direct cloud URL for the repository.

Has anyone else gone into a similar problem with laravel and has an idea of how to resolve it? Or the best solution regarding the same.

Comment: What about using git submodules and use hooks to get the other project updated .
I think it will be hard to make it realtime, but it may help

Comment: I have no idea how this would work. Can you guide me to an article or a blog post regarding this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have not employed these yet, but the repository pattern may be what you want. Read [Decoupling your code in Laravel using Repositiories and Services](http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services) and [Using Repository Pattern in Laravel 5](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/).

Comment: Which version of Laravel are ou using?